# tomcat server not found

Tags: tomcat

I'm trying to configure a tomcat server to start developing servlet/jsp but I get server not found. Here is what I did so far:

Added CLASSPATH to .bash_profile and my servlet compiled successfully.

I typed which java which outputted /usr/bin/java

I then added export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java to .bash_profile

Removed the comments around servlet-mapping as well as the Invoker.

Changed the permission of /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps to world access.

Logged out as root and then logged into my regular account to create WEB-INF/classes under /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps

I then moved the .class from the servlet I compiled to /usr/share/tomcat6/webappsWEB-INF/classes

started a terminal, su to service tomcat6 start then switched user to my normal account and type service tomcat6 status, the output was tomcat 6 running.

Finally, I started my web browser type localhost:8080/servlet/first
and I got server not found. Tried localhost:8080, server not found; however, if I type 127.0.0.1:8080/servlet/first or 127.0.0.1:8080, I get a white page with no error message.

The servlet first will only output Hello World.

I couldn't find the Context path="" docBase="" reloadable="true" line in server.xml

I also search in context.xml, web.xml, and tomcat-users.xml and couldn't find it.

Any suggestions please?

I created a web.xml file inside /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/WEB-INF, which contains the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>first</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>first</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>first</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Still I get server not found. Any thing else I should try?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've said, it sounds like you are trying to run the servlet off of the ROOT webapp of the server.

If so, then the question would be: Do you have an /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml file?

Or, more to the point, **what** do you have under /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/ as far as *.xml files?  That is the location for the individual webapp configuration files as far as putting in the Context entry with the docBase configuration.

Hope that helps.  Let us know.